# Best way to track how many times a user has logged in

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm looking for advice on tracking user logins on my site. I had built a counter that increments on logins but it increments for all users not just one user. I only need it to increment when a specific user logs in. The purpose is to have a welcome message display the first time a user logs into the site. My site is built using ReactJs for the front end and NodeJs for the back. So far I tried using a state with a count set at 0 and then when the login function is run update the count by one. This works but it isn't relative to a user, just to the login function itself. Any advice?

Comment: There's nothing here we can use to help--each user would need to have their own count (or a simple flag) associated with them, persisted with whatever mechanism you're using.

Comment: Can you tell me or point me towards the information I need to do that? I forgot to mention I am also using a SQL database if that helps.

Comment: It's just another field in the user table (or associated metadata table, or however you have things laid out)--on login check that field, if they haven't logged in, do whatever you need to do, and update that field to indicate they've logged in. Any DB-related tutorial should be sufficient--once the user is in session you can do app stuff as usual.